# How to force update .ascx file content in Website project

Tags: asp.net, vs-web-site-project

I have Website project, which contains some .ascx and .aspx files. I have added new element `<asp:TextBox ID="tb1" runat="server" ... />` in .ascx file and I have wrote some code in proper .ascx.cs file using this element: `tb1.Text = "SomeText";`. When I compile this project I recieve following error: The name 'tb1' does not exist in the current context.

How can I force to refresh markup of .ascx page? I use **Website** project and I cannot to change its type to Webapplication.

UPD: I have **Website** project, which has **NOT** .ascx.designers.cs files. And I cannot change type of my project to web application.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's something else happening here, it sounds like the `designer.cs` file might be out of sync. Try cutting and pasting the control back into the markup, or go into the designer file for the user control and add the `TextBox` manually:

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox tb1;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your design file is not connecting with your code behind file.

Can you confirm if you are defining it as follows,

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="yourcontrol.ascx.cs" Inherits="CompleteNameSpace.ClassName" %>
```